# Get Method JSON Data to show in Textfield not working (Error)

Tags: ios, json, swift

How to get JSON data in textfield for GET method. My Json data is as follows,

```
    SUCCESS: {"code":200,
"shop_detail":{"name":"dad","address":"556666","city":"cSC","area":"scsc","street":"vddva","building":"jhkj","description":null}

 "shop_types":
[{"id":7,"name":"IT\/SOFTWARE","merchant_type":"office",}]}
```

My code with header and URL is

```
 func getProfileAPI() {
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorisation": AuthService.instance.tokenId ?? "",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        ]
        print(headers)
        let scriptUrl = "http://haitch.igenuz.com/api/merchant/profile"

        if let url = URL(string: scriptUrl) {
            var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
            urlRequest.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.get.rawValue

            urlRequest.addValue(AuthService.instance.tokenId ?? "", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

            Alamofire.request(urlRequest)
                .responseString { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                    print(response)
                    if let result = response.result.value //    getting the json value from the server
                    {

    }
}
```

After print response I am getting the values of JSON data printed, if I am having textfield like name.text, address.text. I want to show the values as I get through JSON response. If I try below code it fails in Dictionary.

```
if let data = data {
                print(data)
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                    let jsonData:NSDictionary = (data as? NSDictionary)!
                    print(jsonData)
}}
```

Comment: Try this :
 let JSONResponseSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .allowFragments)

Comment: @guru , it doesn't work.

Comment: Does your response really starts with " SUCCESS: thenJSON"?

Comment: @Larme please explain hoe I can get those JSon response value and show it in textfield(ex- for name, address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let code: Int
    let shopDetail: ShopDetail
    let shopTypes: [ShopType]
}

struct ShopDetail: Codable {
    let name, address, area, street, building, city: String
}

struct ShopType: Codable {
    let name, merchantType: String
}
```

And Call

```
func getProfileAPI() {
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorisation": AuthService.instance.tokenId ?? "",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        ]
        print(headers)
        let scriptUrl = "http://haitch.igenuz.com/api/merchant/profile"

        if let url = URL(string: scriptUrl) {
            var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
            urlRequest.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.get.rawValue

            urlRequest.addValue(AuthService.instance.tokenId ?? "", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            Alamofire.request(urlRequest).response { response in
                guard
                    let data = response.data,
                    let json = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                    else { return }
                print("json:", json)
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                    let root = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
                    print(root)
                    self.t1.text! = root.shopDetail.name
                 //   self.t3.text! = root.shopDetail.description
                    print(root.shopDetail.name)
                    print(root.shopDetail.address)
                    for shop in root.shopTypes {
                        self.merchant_Type.text! = shop.merchantType
                        self.t2.text! = shop.name
                        print(shop.name)
                        print(shop.merchantType)
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }}}
```